# Shim Custom Dictionary

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes

I have created a class which is an extension of the dictionary class, which looks as follows:

```
public class PKMRelations : Dictionary<Guid, PKMRelation>, IDisposable
```

I now want to shim the Count method of PKMRelations, so that it returns the value I want. Normally I would just add a few elements, but that is not possible because of the current configuration.

Currently I am unable to figure out how to shim the Count method of dictionary. To be able to do this I have to create a Shim of this specific generic dictionary class.

Is this at all possible, and if so how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Count is not a virtual method in Dictionary, so you cannot override it! However  can you use the new keyword. So, you can add the following propety

```
new int Count 
{
 get
 {
    //Your intercept code here
    return base.Count;
 }
}
```

Comment: That hide the base method, it does not override it. You should understand the implications. But still a good and usefull answer.

Comment: Indeed, I can use this as a temporary workaround, but I would love to be able to shim the dictionary class. Practically all methods should be shimmable, virtual or not, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Count is a property of IDictionary (an interface). This means you can use proxying to wrap the interface with property intercept. Look @ Castle dynamic proxying or other IOC containers (with intercept features).